# Get first available numbers not listed in my MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers

Any SQL to get first numbers not listed in my MySQL database table?
Ex:

Table:
Users

```
ID  | Name   | Number
------------------------
1   | John   | 1456
2   | Phil   | 345
3   | Jenny  | 345612
```

In this case the SQL must return me list of row with number from 1 to 344 and 346 to 1455 and 1457 to 345611

Any suggestions? Maybe with some procedure?

Comment: You want a list of rows that does not exist in the database?

Comment: Yes. I know it sounds mad... but if not I must insert 1000000000 rows

Comment: This can be done using [synthesized] number-tables and joins. However, it is not an ideal solution - explaining the problem better may yield better results.

Comment: @user1840276 Whydo you need 1000000000 rows inserts else? explain that in your question please.

Comment: I have a strong feeling there might be a better way to do whatever it is you want to achieve. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Well My boss App need to handle number assignment to users from 1 to 999999999, and I must suggest on user registration the first 6 available number that are not taken by another user (not in users table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the answer by @pst but would suggest another alternative.

1. Create a new table of unassigned numbers, insert a few thousand rows or so in there.
2. Present some of those numbers to the user.
3. When a number is used, delete it from the unassigned numbers table.
4. Periodically generate more unassigned numbers as needed.

The generation of those unassigned numbers could use the random method suggested by @pst, but using this method you move the uncertainty of how long it'll take to generate a list of unassigned numbers into a batch task rather than having to do it at the front end while the user is waiting.  This probably isn't an issue if the usage of the number space is sparse, but as more of the number space becomes used, it becomes a bigger issue.

Comment: Well, it's not a bad idea, I can make a table with the next 6 available numbers and update it each time a user register on the App and use one of this number.

Comment: @Derealization - That would work, but the idea here was that rather than just having the next 6 numbers in there, why not keep 100 or 1000 or 10,000?  Then just refresh that pool of numbers every so often via a scheduled task (e.g. a MySQL `EVENT`)

Comment: OK, I just need 6 numbers and this solution seems to be the most quickly to develop and the faster one. I also love @pst solution, but I must keep this soft simple for others developers. Thank you Eric for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Given the comment(s), my first approach would be use a "random number" probe. This approach assumes:

1. `Number` is indexed; and
2. There are "significantly less" users than available numbers

Approach:

1. Choose `N` (i.e. 1-10) numbers at random on the client;
2. Query the database for `Number IN (ns..)`, or `Number = n` for `N=1`; then
3. If the number is available can be detected based on *not finding* the requested record(s).

A size of `N=1` is likely "okay" in this case and it is the most trivial to implement although it will require at least 6 database requests to find 6 free numbers. A larger `N` would decrease the number of trips to the database.

Make sure to use transactions.

Comment: You can request N free numbers from the database in one go.  It's a little complicated.  Check out my answer for the mechanism (sorry for self-promotion).

Comment: @JuliusDavies I avoided asking "what's the number used for" on purpose .. for all I know it's a SUPER SECRET ID :x

Comment: I wonder why the down-vote .. not that it matters, but just curious as to what issue(s) this approach may have. (Note the acknowledgment of answering the "intent" and not the "title".)

Comment: I up-voted!  Did someone down-vote?   (I don't have enough points to see the voting).

Comment: @JuliusDavies It doesn't matter, but I do like to know if something I said was in error or if I suggest something that is not a valid approach so I can correct my knowledge if needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use an auto increment column. The database will assign the next number automatically. You don't need to even know what it is at the time of the insert. Just tell the user the number he got, don't give him a choice at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'start', 1 AS number FROM tableA
 UNION
SELECT 'min', number - 1 number FROM tableA
 UNION
SELECT 'max', number + 1 number FROM tableA
 ORDER BY number
```

You can check the answer at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/851de/6

Then you can make a comparison of missing numbers when you populate the next time.

Comment: It can be a start... let me think if I can adapt it or change sql in order to get what I need

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, the approach below might work for you.  It doesn't really answer your specific question, but it probably meets your requirements.

I'm going to assume your requirements cannot change (e.g., presenting users with 6 possible id choices).   Frankly I think it's a bit of a weird requirement, but it makes for some interesting SQL.  :-)

Here's my approach:  generate 10 random numbers.   Filter out any already in the database.  Present 6 of these random numbers to your user.   Random id numbers have very nice properties with respect to transactionality compared to sequential id numbers, so this should scale very nicely should your app become popular.

```
SELECT
  temp.i
FROM
  (
          SELECT 18 AS i   -- 10 random
    UNION SELECT 42        -- numbers.
    UNION SELECT 88        
    UNION SELECT 191       -- Let's assume
    UNION SELECT 192       -- you generated
    UNION SELECT 193       -- these in the
    UNION SELECT 1000      -- application
    UNION SELECT 123456    -- layer.
    UNION SELECT 1092930
    UNION SELECT 9892919
  ) temp
LEFT JOIN
  mytable ON (temp.i = mytable.i)
WHERE
  mytable.i IS NULL       -- filter out collisions
LIMIT
  6                       -- limit results to 6
```

---

**SQL pop quiz time!!!**

- Why does the line "`WHERE mytable.i IS NULL`" filter collisions?  (*Hint*: How can `mytable.i` be null when it's a primary key?)

---

Here's some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (i BIGINT PRIMARY KEY) ;

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (88), (3), (192), (123456) ;
```

Run the query above, and here's the result.   Notice that 88, 192, and 123456 were filtered out, since they would be collisions against the test data.

```
+---------+
| i       |
+---------+
|      18 |
|      42 |
|     191 |
|     193 |
|    1000 |
| 1092930 |
+---------+
```

And how to generate those random numbers?   Probably rand() * 9223372036854775807 would work.    (Assuming you don't want negative numbers!)